# karma junit report crashing

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, karma-runner

I am trying to run karma on a project, and its crashing on running the junit report, although it works with the same project in a similarly configured machinne.

When trying to run

```
karma start '<path-to>/karma.conf.js' --reporters junit --single-run --junitReporter.outputFile karmaoutpu
```

And I am getting this traceback:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.17 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Linux)]: Connected on socket fAqoa8mrX6WgaHTam1Ut with id 5898608
ERROR [karma]: [TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined]
TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
  at [object Object].onBrowserStart (<project-path>/node_modules/karma/lib/reporters/base.js:14:20)
```

Checking that `base.js`file, I have this snippet:

```
  this.onRunStart = function() {
    this._browsers = [];
  };

  this.onBrowserStart = function(browser) {
    this._browsers.push(browser);  // <this._browsers is undefined here!>
  };
```

If I force the initiation of the this._browsers array inside `onBrowserStart`, 
I get other errors elsewhere - but this tells me that `onRunStart` is not being called  -
so I am probably missing some initialization. What could be that it fails, being that
the same project, with the same versions of Node packages work in an Ubuntu system (I am on Fedora 20)

The `dots` reporter plug-in, on the other hand, works flawlessly.

Versions for  karma, and karma related packages installed:

```
    karma 0.12.17
├─┬ karma-chai@0.0.1
│ └── chai@1.6.1
├── karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.4
├─┬ karma-coffee-preprocessor@0.1.3
│ └─┬ coffee-script@1.7.1
│   └── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── karma-firefox-launcher@0.1.3
├── karma-html2js-preprocessor@0.1.0
├── karma-jasmine@0.1.5
├─┬ karma-junit-reporter@0.1.0
│ └── xmlbuilder@0.4.2
├── karma-mocha@0.1.6
├── karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4
├── karma-requirejs@0.2.2
├── karma-script-launcher@0.1.0
...
├─┬ phantomjs@1.9.2-2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was caused by an old version of the junit-reporter module - the version I had didn't work with the new `karma` version - the other developers which didn't face the issue were running an older karma as well.

It is documented on the project here:
https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-junit-reporter/issues/11